# VB How do I dynamically create a groupbox to appear and group radiobuttons which are in an array?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, button, groupbox

I have an array of 2 `RadioButtons`. One displays the text "TRUE", the other "FALSE", and they appear when a user selects a TRUE/FALSE style question.

However, when multiple TRUE/FALSE style questions are selected, the `RadioButtons` all seem to be linked, rather than linked in the pairs which they appear in. E.g. if a 3 question quiz has 2 TRUE/FALSE style questions, then when you select an answer on one question, it removes the answer on the other TRUE/FALSE style question.

Code for reference: (inside a For loop (k) and inside a select case (when a truefalse style question is selected))

```
grpTrueFalse(k) = New GroupBox 
grpTrueFalse(k).Location = New Point((X - 10), (Y - 10))
grpTrueFalse(k).BackColor = Color.Transparent
grpTrueFalse(k).Visible = False
grpTrueFalse(k).Width = 250 : grpTrueFalse(k).Height = 50
frmQuizBuild.Controls.Add(grpTrueFalse(k))

rdbtrue(k) = New RadioButton : rdbtrue(k).Location = New Point((X + 120), Y)
rdbtrue(k).Text = "TRUE" : rdbtrue(k).Font = New Font("Arial", 15)
rdbtrue(k).BackColor = Color.Transparent
frmQuizBuild.Controls.Add(rdbtrue(k))

rdbfalse(k) = New RadioButton : rdbfalse(k).Location = New Point(X, Y)
rdbfalse(k).Text = "TRUE" : rdbfalse(k).Font = New Font("Arial", 15)
rdbfalse(k).BackColor = Color.Transparent
frmQuizBuild.Controls.Add(rdbfalse(k))
```

For the record the `GroupBox` appears on top of the `RadioButtons` and isn't really doing anything at the moment.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the form? The `RadioButtons` should appear inside the `GroupBox`, not being under it.

Comment: The groupbox is being created then the radiobuttons are being created below it somehow. How do i add a screenshot?

Comment: Click on edit, and there is an option to add an image in the toolbar. Are you creating the controls in code? It's much easier to just drag them onto the form

Comment: Basically my program is a quiz program, the user can create a quiz and they can how many qusetions they want. When they select that, the quiz starts being made, then they can select what question type it is (3 options, one of which is the True/False). This means the radiobuttons are being made in runtime and I cant drag them on because I don't know how many are being created.

Comment: And they're being created underneath/behind the `GroupBox`?

Comment: Yeah the groupbox is covering the radiobuttons, and doesn't seem to be grouping whatever is underneath it

Comment: Add the radio buttons to the group box like `grpTrueFalse(k).Controls.Add(rdbtrue(k))`

Comment: @Jinx88909 Thankyou! It worked, such a simple fix!

Comment: @David Thankyou for trying to help! Much appreciated.

Comment: @rwan See my answer below for the most efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to be something like:

```
Dim arrRButton(1) As RadioButton
arrRButton(0) = New RadioButton
arrRButton(1) = New RadioButton

Dim GroupBox1 As New GroupBox
 With GroupBox1
  .Controls.Add(rdbTrue(k))
  .Controls.Add(rdbFalse(k))
 End With
```

You can also set the location by using a similar `With` block. (Eg; `With arrRButton(0)` Then `.Location = x`, `.Text = x` etc)

Comment: Thanks that looks much better programming than what I am currently using, I'll try and use that instead.

Comment: @rwan if it helps, upvote/accept the answer. That's how we say thanks on here :)

Comment: @Jinx88909 Okay have done, my reputation is too low to display it however I think it still gets counted :)

Comment: @rwan I got an upvote, whether that was you or not I don't know. Did you accept the answer (Using the tick)? That will allow future users with the same issue to see the solution that solved your issue.

Comment: @David Just ticket it, thanks for the answer. I'm new to coding and this website as you can probably tell :p

Answer (score 0):

If what I understand is correct you could just use a checkbox.

If that's not it
Have you tried to add an event handler to the radiobuttons ?
so:

```
 Addhandler.radioButton1_CheckedChanged , AddressOf EventHandler
```

With EventHandler being the sub or class you're using.

Does this make any sense?

Comment: I tried to use checkboxes however I need it so you can only check 1 box at a time and so I'd need lines saying "if this is checked then uncheck all of these". If i have radiobuttons on the form then the groupbox works however due to dynamically creating them or because theyre in an array it isn't working. Also I don't think I can event handler the radiobuttons as that isn't needed for my quiz program.

Comment: I miss understood you. Could you just do
frmQuizBuild.Groupbox1.Controls.Add(rdbtrue(k))?